# include of header with ifdef

Tags: c++, header, include, conditional-compilation

I've tried placing the following in my C++ code:

```
#ifdef _WIN32  
#include "stdafx.h"  
#endif
```

but I getan error:

```
PCH warning: header stop cannot be in a macro of #if block. An IntelliSense PCH file was not generated.
```

I'm trying to let my code work both on windows and linux, stdafx.h does not work on linux where it's a must on visual studio.

Is there another way to use the include with ifdef?

Comment: You should copy/paste your error messages to avoid typos.

Comment: PCH's have funny rules associated with them.  One of them is that you can't use it in conditional blocks (another is it must be the first non-comment statement in the source file, I believe).  You'll need to include `"stdafx.h"` unconditionally, but provide an empty (or logically empty — or maybe logically equivalent file) `stdafx.h` file on Linux.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good to know!

Comment: Search around [Creating Precompiled Header Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szfdksca.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: One way to take care of this problem is to go into your project's properties (right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, choose properties), then go to `Configuration Properties` `->` `C/C++` -> `Advanced` where you will see a value labeled "Forced Include File".  Add `stdafx.h` to this field, then you can remove `#include "stdafx.h"` from all of the project's source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not do that with precompiled header and using Microsoft MSVC. The MSVC totally ignores all code (and whatever garbage) lines that precede that `#include "stdafx.h"` line. As result the `#endif` will be unexpected to it.

Put that `#ifdef _WIN32` and what not inside of stdafx.h.

Answer (score 0):

I have just created an empty stdafx.h. With follow content for solutions without pre-compiled headers

```
#pragma once
//this is only for using Common modules with Precompiled headers. We can't disable it using a preprocessor(
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/36271896/6160632
```